# Eclipse runtime compiling?

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

I am new in eclipse. Where is Eclipse running time after compiling ? I want to compare my two java programs. How long does it take to compile my program. I try to look at Window Console, but it only show end time after compiling. Anyone know ?

Answer (score 0):

For your runtime, add this line to the top of your main method:

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then this line at the end:

```
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long difference = t2 - t1;

System.out.println("The program took " + ((difference + 0.0) / 1000) " seconds to run.");
```

As for compile time, I believe Eclipse should show it in a little box above the console, but it doesn't really matter much - is there any reason you want the compile time?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said above, I want to compare my two java programs performance. Which one is faster.

Comment: @vallen Then use the code I gave you. You don't need the compilation time for performance comparison, just the run time. Let me know if there's anything else you want added to the answer.